# Execute commands as if they're being executed directly in the terminal

Tags: rust, terminal

The following code defines custom terminal commands (`KeyboardShortcut`) and executes them:

```
use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use std::process::Command;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;

struct KeyboardShortcut {
    key: char,
    description: &'static str,
    command: &'static str,
}

impl KeyboardShortcut {
    fn execute_command(&self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
        Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(self.command).status();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    // Do something in raw mode

    let keyboard_shortcuts = vec![KeyboardShortcut {
        key: 'f',
        description: "Feat: adds a new feature to the application",
        command: "ls --color=always",
    }];

    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    // In the actual application, I'm using `match`.
    keyboard_shortcuts[0].execute_command(&mut stdout)
}
```

Notice that I had to add `--color=always` to the command. This is because commands won't display colors if they are not executed directly in the terminal (in this case, they are being executed from a Rust file).

Is there a way to tell `Command` to execute commands as if they were being executed directly in the terminal? So that I don't have enable colors (with flags) every time I want to execute a command?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3b458a121dd1aa55c0c09b1951a0858)

Comment: It's not "in the terminal", it's _with one of the standard file descriptors attached to a TTY_. Connect your program's file descriptors to a pseudoterminal rather than a pipe, and there you are -- on, as you have an answer advising you, use a program like `script` or `unbuffer` that does the work of setting up a ptty for you. The program being run is literally invoking the C call `isatty()` on one of its file descriptors (if deciding whether to syntax-highlight stdout, almost certainly on stdout) and using the result to set the default behavior.

Comment: You _could_, then, do the work of setting up a ptty in native Rust -- it would just be considerably more effort.

Comment: for your aliases to be considered (to customize `ls` from `.bashrc` for example), you need a login shell. It's not so easy to obtain...

Comment: See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html for docs on how the program being run is detecting whether its stdout is going to a TTY.

Comment: @prog-fh, a login shell should be executing `.bash_profile`; any interactive shell should execute `.bashrc`, and aliases should be in the latter. Still, though, I agree that invoking an interactive shell noninteractively is a general bad idea.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have struggled a lot with these questions of shell opening, in the past, and I still make the confusion between the properties of interactive/login shells! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the command with `sh` in `execute_command`, wrap it in [`script`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) from `util-linux`, like so:

```
fn execute_command(&self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
    Command::new("script").arg("-qec").arg(self.command).arg("/dev/null").status();
}
```

The additional `.arg("/dev/null")` stops `script` from writing a log of all console output, which is what its intended purpose actually is.

Note however that ls doesn't print in colour by default - if it does for you, it's because of a shell alias. However we can prove this change worked by executing `ls --color=auto`.

```
let keyboard_shortcuts = vec![KeyboardShortcut {
    key: 'f',
    description: "Feat: adds a new feature to the application",
    command: "ls --color=auto",
}];
```

Which should now print in colour.